# How to correctly track button clicks in Big Cartel (with Facebook pixel)

Tags: event-tracking, facebook-pixel, bigcartel

I'm stuck with setting up correctly FB pixel code, events like page view and content view work fine, but seems I missing something with tracking button clicks like "AdToCart" or "InitiateCheckout" events. Tried to play with a code, but didn't figure out it.

Here is the original code I tried to implement from Facebook for Add to Cart event.

```
<script>
<button id="button add-to-cart-button">AddtoCart</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#addToCartButton').click(function() {
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {currency: "EUR", value: {{ option.price }}});
  });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify, the theme I'm using is Luna, I tried the easiest way, to add these events with the event manager, but it messed up and shows 2 duplicates of such events just after loading the page. Also, for some reason setup via GTM doesn't show active pixel on the website, seems like not working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot have multiple ids to one element. The id is unique, so id="add-to-cart-button"

Second, the id is 'add-to-cart-button', so the jquery selector should match that: #add-to-cart-button not #addToCartButton